# how to make an element unselectable but able to start selection from it

Tags: html, css, selection

I want to make some `<span>`s in a `<pre>` element unselectable, but if I use the CSS property `user-select: none`, I won't be able to start selection from these `<span>`s (click at these elements and move mouse to select other lines) as well.

```css
#pseudo-ele::before{
    content: "This line is unselectable, while you can start selection from it."
}
```

```html
<pre>
This line is selectable.
<span style="user-select: none;">This line is unselectable, and you cannot start selection from it.</span>
<span id="pseudo-ele"></span>
This line is also selectable.
</pre>
```

I noticed that one can start selection from `::before` or `::after` pseudo-elements, but they are not selectable themselves. However, pseudo-elements are quite inconvenient in my situation.

Is it possible to make a normal element unselectable but able to start the selection from it? If so, how can I do that?

Comment: I don't understand what starting a selection from that second line means. Does it mean if I put the cursor half way along it say then I cannot select the next line?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I've modified the question to make it more precise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having an extra span separate, have it wrapping the unselectable span and overlay it with a before pseudo element that has no content but has the same dimensions.

```html
<style>
  #pseudo-ele {
    position: relative;
    width: fit-content;
    height: fit-content;
  }
  
  #pseudo-ele::before {
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
  }
</style>
<pre>
This line is selectable.
<span id="pseudo-ele"><span style="user-select: none; position: relative;">This line is unselectable, while you can start selection from it.</span></span>
This line is also selectable.
</pre>
```